# how do i insert a catalog/category_list block from my module layout xml

Tags: php, xml, magento, templates

I'm trying to make a module that inserts some JS tracking code at `"before_body_end"` on selected pages. So far I've successfully injected my own block with a `.phtml` template containing tracking JS on product views with this code in my layout XML:

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="before_body_end">
        <block type="catalog/product_view" name="trackingjs_product" template="company/module/product.phtml"></block>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

And making sure the block type is catalog/product_view so I can access the product class and get information such as the current product ID.  My problem is with the product listing pages. I tried similar code for `catalog/product_list` but that didn't work.

It seem that I have to set it to `catalog_product_view` for it to output anything at all, but with that I don't have access to the product collection. Any ideas on how I could access the product collection or how to make it work on `catalog/product_list` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need product or category information, no need such blocks. core/template is find as long as you have Mage::registry('current_product') and Mage::registry('current_category') to retrieve product and category information.

But if you're kind of prefering your way I suggest to do it like

```
<catalog_category_layered>
<reference name="before_body_end">
    <block type="catalog/product_list" name="trackingjs_list" template="company/module/list.phtml"></block>
</reference>
</catalog_category_layered>
<catalog_category_default>
<reference name="before_body_end">
    <block type="catalog/product_list" name="trackingjs_list" template="company/module/list.phtml"></block>
</reference>
</catalog_category_default>
```

Comment: I was 99% certain that I'd tried that with category_default and layered, but obviously not. Worked fine! And I didn't know that about Mage::registry, very useful information - will award you the right answer. Thanks again!